# How do I parse a Rich Text in PowerShell in order to replace elements?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have a requirement to read each rich text field and then edit the content with unordered lists rather than ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to find and replace characters rather than parse all of the html. Try this:

```
# Home Item
$rootId = "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

# Get only the immediate children
$items = @((Get-ChildItem -Path "master:" -ID $rootId))
foreach($item in $items) {
    $html = $item.Text
    if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($html)) { continue }
    $newText = $html.Replace("<ul>", "<ol>").Replace("</ul>", "</ol>")
    $item.Text = $newText
}
```